# Android animating image pieces and device compatibility

Tags: android

I am creating an application which on one view has an image of an elephant. this elephant needs to animate various parts of his body such as eyes, trunk, spraying water, and also the background/horizon movements.  I have briefly tried positioning each element(eye, trunk, etc) in a `RelativeLayout` using margins and relative positions so that the picture looks correct.

When i change the screen size via eclipse layout editor everything gets out of place.  I read that using `RelativeLayout` with margins and relative positions will be the best alternative to `AbsoluteLayout`, but i can't seem to get each piece in the right spot while keeping some compatibility of devices.

**What is the best way of positioning pieces of the image to complete a full image which will also allow me to animate/translate/rotate/etc each piece and support a large variety of devices?**

I thought that maybe using OpenGL or Canvas might be the way this is done properly, but i don't see how these would resolve the problems i've mentioned.

I have created the iOS version of this application and it was extremely easy to set this up.  I don't quite understand how applications line up sprites to make a scene which is compatible among a large variety of screen sizes/densities.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to scale the elements of your big picture to fit the High , medium and low screen densities .

To do this you will have to resize each set of elements and copy them into separate drawable folders :
/res

drawable-hdpi

drawable-ldpi

drawable-mdpi

also you can create a dedicated layout for each screen category if needed but first try just to scale the images and copy them into the folders and launch your application.

A good link to see also : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

P.S: make sure to use dp not pix as measurement unit on your layouts , also the use of absolutelayout is not a good choice it's deprecated.

Comment: alignment issues still come up even with different sized pieces. im having the feeling that what i want isn't possible.